# PL/SQL Trigger Recursive Error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a PL/SQL statement level trigger that will execute after an insert or update statement. What the trigger will do is for products with a quantity (p_qoh) of 50 or more, their product discount will be doubled. Except products can't have more than a discount of 50%. My trigger complies successfully but when I try to update the products table I get a "maximum number of recursive SQL levels reached". Any help is greatly apprecaited.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_AlterDiscount
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF p_qoh, p_discount ON product
DECLARE
  v_p_code      product.p_code%type;
  v_p_discount  product.p_discount%type;
  v_p_qoh       product.p_qoh%type;
CURSOR v_cursor IS SELECT p_discount, p_qoh, p_code FROM product;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cursor;
LOOP
  FETCH v_cursor INTO v_p_discount, v_p_qoh, v_p_code;
  EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  IF v_p_qoh > 50 AND v_p_discount <= .25 THEN
    UPDATE product SET p_discount = v_p_discount *2 WHERE v_p_code = p_code;
  ELSIF v_p_qoh > 50 AND v_p_discount > .26 THEN
    UPDATE product SET p_discount = .50 WHERE v_p_code = p_code;
  ELSIF v_p_qoh > 50 AND v_p_discount = 0 THEN
    UPDATE product SET p_discount = .05 WHERE v_p_code = p_code;
  ELSE
    NULL;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Your trigger is on `product`.  You're then updating `lab9_product`.  Are those really supposed to be the same table?  If they are, that explains the recursion.  If they are not the same, is there a trigger on `lab9_product` that modifies `product`?

Comment: They are the same table, there is only a product table. Meant to remove the tags. Is the recursion error from me performing an update inside the trigger? Just not sure why I'm getting the error or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update value of the record that it's updating or inserting.

You can use FOR EACH ROW Trigger with Pseudorecord. [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_AlterDiscount
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF p_qoh, p_discount ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.p_qoh > 50 AND :NEW.p_discount <= .25 THEN
    :NEW.p_discount := :NEW.p_discount *2;
  ELSIF :NEW.p_qoh > 50 AND :NEW.p_discount > .26 THEN
    :NEW.p_discount := .50;
  END IF; 
END;
/
```

Edited:

For the function like this row level trigger is better than statement level trigger because there are 2 problems that you must consider.

First, recursive error.  the error occur when you update on the same table(and column for updated trigger) that trigger fired. trigger will fire themselves again and again.

Ex. You updated (p_qoh=100,p_discount=0) then trigger fired.

With condition, trigger updated (p_discount=.5) then trigger fired again.

With condition, trigger updated (p_discount=.1) then trigger fired again.

With condition, trigger updated (p_discount=.2) then trigger fired again.

With condition, trigger updated (p_discount=.4) then trigger fired again.

With condition, trigger updated (p_discount=.5) then trigger fired again.

With condition, trigger updated (p_discount=.5) again then trigger fired again. ...Infinite!!!

To avoid this you can add more condition like below for stop trigger when p_discount=.5

```
ELSIF v_p_qoh > 50 AND v_p_discount = .5 THEN
    NULL;
ESLE ...
```

Second, You will get wrong data like previously example. You just need p_discount=.05 but you got p_discount=.5

To avoid this you need some control data, update it to be 1 when you update data to give the trigger know which record have updated. update it to be 0 when trigger update the data. With this trigger will fire only 1 time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_AlterDiscount
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF p_qoh, p_discount ON product
DECLARE
  v_p_code      product.p_code%type;
  v_p_discount  product.p_discount%type;
  v_p_qoh       product.p_qoh%type;
CURSOR v_cursor IS SELECT p_discount, p_qoh, p_code FROM product WHEN p_ctrl =1;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cursor;
LOOP
  FETCH v_cursor INTO v_p_discount, v_p_qoh, v_p_code;
  EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  IF v_p_qoh > 50 AND v_p_discount <= .25 THEN
    UPDATE product 
        SET p_discount = v_p_discount *2, 
        SET p_ctrl = 0 
    WHERE v_p_code = p_code;
  ELSIF v_p_qoh > 50 AND v_p_discount > .26 THEN
    UPDATE product 
        SET p_discount = .50, 
        SET p_ctrl = 0 
    WHERE v_p_code = p_code;
  ELSIF v_p_qoh > 50 AND v_p_discount = 0 THEN
    UPDATE product 
        SET p_discount = .05,
        SET p_ctrl = 0  
    WHERE v_p_code = p_code;
  ELSE
    UPDATE product 
        SET p_ctrl = 0  
    WHERE v_p_code = p_code;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Ex. You updated (p_qoh=100,p_discount=0, p_ctrl=1) then trigger fired.

With condition, trigger updated (p_discount=.05, p_ctrl=0) then trigger fired.

With condition of select statement will not found any row. Done!!!

Comment: This would easily work for a row level trigger but I'm trying to create a statement level trigger to perform the same function.

Comment: @StevieP - Why would you want to do this in a statement-level trigger?  It would be way less efficient and way more complicated.

Comment: Mainly just working on my PL/SQL skills, very new to the language. Trying to figure ways of doing them both row level and statement level. Feel like I have a better hold on row level triggers.

Comment: 2 problem when you use statement level and example way to avoid it. See it on edited answer.